# How to install SWT for eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently downloaded eclipse Kepler to learn to use SWT, I also downloaded the SWT zip folder. 
The instructions on eclipse web site states that I should import the zip folder to `Existing Projects into Workspace`. I have done this, but no project shows on the `Projects`  form field, I have been googling since morning to get info on how to install `SWT` on `Eclipse Kepler` but I have not found any help.

Please I need help on this, as I am faced with a project that needs rich look and feel. All replies would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all.

Comment: Did you mean add the SWT library to the classpath of your project?

Comment: yes please, that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, Ignorance was the case, cos I have never done any SWT before. so this reply is for all those who are as Ignorant as I was.
The jar file representing the SWT library is found in the plugin folder, of the eclipse installation, to add the jar file to a project you would have to follow these steps:

> Right Click on the project Name 
>   Select Properties 
>   Choose the Java Build Path from the dialog that appears 
>   select Libraries > click on the Add External JARs... 
>   Select the SWT jar file from the plugins folder in the eclipse folder represented by org.eclipse.swt.windowing_system>_.jar 
>   
> and click on OK to exit the dialog`,

then you are ready to play